# how to use lodash groupBy, sumBy and orderBy and keep structure of array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array of objects and I want to group by app name and then sum by time for that app and then order by so that will give me the top most used app without changing the structure of the array

```
[ 
{ appName: GoogleChrome, Position: GoogleChrome, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51", Totaltime:1},
{ appName: GoogleChrome, Position: GoogleChrome, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1},
{ appName: GoogleChrome, Position: GoogleChrome, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51", Totaltime:1},
{ appName: Code, Position: Code, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1},
{ appName: Code, Position: Code, start: "2017/04/07 05:00:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:15:51",Totaltime:15},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:10:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:20:51",Totaltime:10},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:30:00" end:"2017/04/07 05:50:51",Totaltime:20},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1} ]
```

and I want the following result

```
[ 
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:32},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:30:00" end:"2017/04/07 05:50:51",Totaltime:32},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:32},
{ appName: Slack, Position: Slack, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:32},
{ appName: Code, Position: Code, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:16},
{ appName: Code, Position: Code, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:16},
{ appName: GoogleChrome, Position: GoogleChrome, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51", Totaltime:3},
{ appName: GoogleChrome, Position: GoogleChrome, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:3},
{ appName: GoogleChrome, Position: GoogleChrome, start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51" end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51", Totaltime:3} ]
```

once I get the result I'll do a `_dropright` and from the Total time element.
Please understand the above is dummy data.Not actual values.

Comment: you should format the input as code so it's easier to see what the code or the data looks like.

Comment: sorry abt that ...here it is

Comment: it would be nicer if you indented the data with 4 spaces and wrapped the line aftter each record. But to your question: I don't see what your problem is. Why don't you loop over that data and sort and sum up the values you want sorted and summed up?

Comment: yes I have edited the qs...let appData1 = _(appData)
                    .groupBy(x => x.appName)
                    .map((value, key) =>({
                      appName: key,
                      Time: _.sumBy(value,'Time'),
                      End: value.End,
                      Position: value.Position,
                      Start: value.startDatetime,
                    })).value();let appData2 =_.values(_.orderBy(appData1, ["Time"],['desc']));

Comment: the above doesnt work and does not give me the result struct i need

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your second set of sample data had the Totaltime modified. I'm not sure if this was a typo or intentional, since you said you didn't want to modify the original array, but my solution below assumes that all values (including Totaltime) are left in the exact same way as when we started. Also, the dummy data needed some slight modification to work as-is, so I added some small tweaks (commas, strings etc.) to make it run.

Finally, I moved items around in the original list (without modifying any values) to show that the entries were indeed sorted.

The code below takes the list:

- Groups by appName
- Sorts the multiple entries with a given appName in descending order of longest time
- Sorts the grouped appName entries by their summed times, in descending order
- Flattens everything together into a single array

If you don't want/need the individual entries also sorted within the appName, you can just remove the `.map()` call.

```js
const data = [
{ appName: 'GoogleChrome', Position: 'GoogleChrome', start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51", Totaltime:1},
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1},
{ appName: 'GoogleChrome', Position: 'GoogleChrome', start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51", Totaltime:1},
{ appName: 'Code', Position: 'Code', start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1},
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: "2017/04/07 05:30:00", end:"2017/04/07 05:50:51",Totaltime:20},
{ appName: 'Code', Position: 'Code', start: "2017/04/07 05:00:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:15:51",Totaltime:15},
{ appName: 'GoogleChrome', Position: 'GoogleChrome', start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1},
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: "2017/04/07 05:10:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:20:51",Totaltime:10},
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: "2017/04/07 05:31:51", end:"2017/04/07 05:31:51",Totaltime:1} ];

function reorder(list) {
    const newList = _(list)
        .groupBy('appName')
        .map(element => {
            return _.sortBy(element, innerElement => {
                return -innerElement.Totaltime;
            });
        })
        .sortBy(element => {
            return -_.sumBy(element, 'Totaltime');
        })
        .flatten()
        .valueOf();


    console.log(newList);
    return newList;
}

reorder(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Result:

```
[ { appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: '2017/04/07 05:30:00', end: '2017/04/07 05:50:51', Totaltime: 20 },
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: '2017/04/07 05:10:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:20:51', Totaltime: 10 },
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', Totaltime: 1 },
{ appName: 'Slack', Position: 'Slack', start: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', Totaltime: 1 },
{ appName: 'Code', Position: 'Code', start: '2017/04/07 05:00:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:15:51', Totaltime: 15 },
{ appName: 'Code', Position: 'Code', start: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', Totaltime: 1 },
{ appName: 'GoogleChrome', Position: 'GoogleChrome', start: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', Totaltime: 1 },
{ appName: 'GoogleChrome', Position: 'GoogleChrome', start: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', Totaltime: 1 },
{ appName: 'GoogleChrome', Position: 'GoogleChrome', start: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', end: '2017/04/07 05:31:51', Totaltime: 1 } ]
```